# ASP.NET MVC Portfolio CMS

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, portfolio

I am going to implement portfolio website for architect using ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC. 
Do you know some CMS that I can use to implement portfolio website? Person should be able to manage completed projects, add details and pictures to them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Koobo CMS (http://kooboo.com/)
It is completely MVC/C#, flexible and modern.

Comment: btw I used it to create construction company site. It has its own kind of database you may setup via web interface and users can use it, add edit or remove items with its own templates etc. I like it.